# Create check constraint on HSTORE to maintain specific succession of data

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, check-constraints, hstore

Question is regarding check constraint on HSTORE field in Postgres.

```
create table archives_seasonmodel
    (episodes      hstore)
```

This is very shortened version of table I have, but just for example its ok.

Episodes contains data in the following format:

```
{ 
1 => 2020-03-01, 2 => 2020-03-07,  5=> 2020-03-29, 3=> 2020-03-14
}
```

Where key is always a positive digit and value is a date.

I want to create a constraint that would check any new data for following condition:

– each date in a key/value pair should be greater or equal comparative to previous key/value pair ordered by keys ASC.

Good data:

```
{ 
1 => 2020-03-01, 2 => 2020-03-07,  5=> 2020-03-29, 3=> 2020-03-14
}
2020-03-29 >= 2020-03-14 >=   2020-03-07 >=  2020-03-01

5 >=3 >=2 >=1
```

Bad data:

```
{ 
1 => 2020-03-01, 2 => 2020-06-07,  5=> 2020-03-29, 3=> 2020-03-14
}
2020-03-29 >= 2020-03-14 not >=   2020-06-07 >=  2020-03-01

5 >=3 >=2 >=1
```

`2020-03-14 not >=   2020-06-07` but it should be as `2020-03-14` has key `3`  `2020-06-07` has key `2`. Date of key `3` should be greater or equal to date with key `2` because `3 > 2`.

Is it possible to create such constraint or it is just out of reality???

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a function for checking the condition. Use the hstore function `each()` and aggregation function `array_agg()`.

```
create or replace function check_episodes(hstore)
returns boolean language sql as $$
    select array_agg(key order by key::int) = array_agg(key order by value::date)
    from each($1)
$$;

create table archives_seasonmodel (
    episodes hstore check (check_episodes(episodes))
);
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ff5581184d8d7686228f0754107ecf48)

Comment: @AlekseiKhatkevich  Caution:  keys and values are text strings in hstore.  The left side of the comparison should perhaps be `array_agg(key order by key::int)`

Comment: @MikeOrganek - good point. Also, the second array expression may be `array_agg(key order by value::date)`